# Sonarqube doesn't work on Docker

Tags: docker, sonarqube, dockerhub

I'm running a docker container; it's sonarqube: When I use this command:

```
docker run -d --restart=always --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 sonarqube
```

The container runs well, but when I use the command to run and to configure the database, this command:

```
docker run -d --restart=always --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=my_user_name -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=my_password -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgres://host:123qweasdzxc@ec2-54-243-28-109.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/database?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory sonarqube
```

I'm getting this error:

```
"docker run" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker run --help'.
Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...] [flags]
Run a command in a new container
```

What is wrong? or How to fix this little problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single quotes in your "SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL" environment variable. I just tried to delimit that particular variable so that docker understands it as a complete string with it's starting & ending point. Due to some reason, it was unable to fetch the IMAGE_NAME argument which was required to run the container.

```
docker run -d --restart=always --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=my_user_name -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=my_password -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL='jdbc:postgres://host:123qweasdzxc@ec2-54-243-28-109.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/database?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory' sonarqube
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Thank, this answer helped to me. I solved this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The sonarqube docker image latest version did not work for me either, However below image worked for me. If you using docker for learning purpose you can follow below steps. Please note, By default, the image will use an embedded H2 database that is not suited for production.

Run below command to pull the docker image:

```
docker pull sonarqube:lts-community
```

Run below command to create the docker container for sonarqube:

-h, --hostname string    Container host name
-d, --detach   Run container in background and print container ID

```
docker run --name sanarqube -h sonarqube -p 8084:9000 -d sonarqube
```

search sonarqube UI in your favourite browser

```
http://YOUR-IP:8084/
```

Then to stop the conatiner

```
docker stop sonarqube
```

Then to start the conatiner

```
docker start sonarqube
```

Hope this help!